# Initialize string producer from CSV

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a CSV file that contains pairs of filenames of images and a label. I would like to load those images.

```
# Queue for reading input pairs
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([MY_CSV_FILE])

# Read CSV input pairs and label
pair_list_reader = tf.TextLineReader()
pair_list_key, pair_list_value = pair_list_reader.read(filename_queue)
record_defaults = [[''], [''], [-1]]
img1_path, img2_path, label = tf.decode_csv(pair_list_value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

# Load image 1
img1_filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(img1_path)
```

As you can see, I read in the CSV file line-by-line and then try to initialize a second input producer using the filename I get from the CSV decoder.

I get an error in the last line, though:

```
  File "tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 138, in string_input_producer
    "fraction_of_%d_full" % capacity)
  File "tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 106, in _input_producer
    enq = q.enqueue_many([input_tensor])
  File "tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 192, in enqueue_many
    batch_dim = ret.inputs[1].get_shape()[0]
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 427, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error due to the incompatible *shapes* of `img1_path` (a 0-D, or scalar, Tensor) and the expected `string_tensor` argument to [`tf.train.string_input_producer`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) (a 1-D, or vector, Tensor).

Fortunately, the solution is simple, using [`tf.expand_dims`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#expand_dims) to convert `img1_path` to a (one-element) vector:

```
# Convert img1_path from a scalar to a 1-element vector.
img1_path = tf.expand_dims(img1_path, 0)
```

Keeping track of the shapes of tensors can be tricky, so TensorFlow provides the [`Tensor.get_shape()`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.get_shape) method, which you can call to get information about the shape of any tensor object. For example:

```
print img1_path.get_shape()
# ==> "TensorShape([])" (a 0-dimensional tensor, or scalar)
img1_path = tf.expand_dims(img1_path, 0)
print img1_path.get_shape()
# ==> "TensorShape([Dimension(1)])" (a 1-dimensional tensor with length 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How do I find out the dimensionality of a tensor?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use the `Tensor.get_shape()` method.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot.